# Expand an argument into a string

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I would like to build a TeX macro that would transform its argument by expanding every number into a sequence of letter (always the same letter). For example `3(2)2(1)` should produce `AAA(AA)AA(A)`.

I already found a way to produce an arbitrary number of `A` from  a number:

```tex
\newcommand\expandtoA[1]{%
  \foreach \index in {1, ..., #1} {A}
}
```

Thus, `\expandtoA{10}` will be expanded into `AAAAAAAAAA`.

But, I am looking at a way to find all the numbers in the argument and substitute each of them by the number of A's it represents.

Comment: What about `2(11)`?  Should it read "one and one" (`AA(AA)`) or "eleven" (`AA(AAAAAAAAAAA)`)?

Comment: It should be eleven `AA(AAAAAAAAAAA)`. But, If you have a solution for any of them, I'm taking it. :-)

Comment: Nesting is out of use... There should be only one level of parenthesis at the time.

Comment: If you want to handle with nesting, maybe you should include more examples of what you need.

Comment: No, nesting is really not necessary. It would be out-of-scope for my purpose. It is really a flat parenthesis expression.

Comment: For now, I am looking towards `xparse` and `l3regex`.

Comment: note that `\foreach` does not work by expansion so the name you suggest here is misleading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\foreach` from OpTeX works by expansion:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does work via expansion so as shown works in `\typeout` as well as the typeset paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz#1{\zzz#1(\relax)}
\def\zzz#1(#2){\zzA{#1}\ifx\relax#2\else(\zzA{#2})\expandafter\zzz\fi}
\def\zzA#1{\ifnum\numexpr0#1\relax>0 A\expandafter\zzA\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}\fi}

\begin{document}

\zz{3(2)2(1)}

\typeout{\zz{3(2)2(1)}}

\end{document}
```

puts

```
AAA(AA)AA(A)
```

on the terminal.

Comment: Nice answer, it has very few dependencies, but the other answers are quite interesting as well!

Answer (score 8):

Here's an expandable approach using `expl3`.  `\Replicate[<tokens>]{<token list>}` It will loop over your input `<token list>` looking for any sequence of digits and replacing them by that amount of repetitions of the input `<tokens>` (by default `A`).  Everything else that is not a digit will be just forwarded to the output, so you can have things like

```latex
\Replicate{3(2)2(1)}
\Replicate[Z]{3(2)2(1)}
\Replicate[(Z)]{3(2)2(1)}
\Replicate[Z]{3 \textbf{(2) 2}( 1 )}
\edef\zzzzzzzzzzzz{\Replicate[Z]{3\textbf{(2)2}(1)}}
\texttt{\meaning\zzzzzzzzzzzz}
```

produce:

> [image]

---

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \Replicate { O{A} m }
  { \perror_replicate:nn {#1} {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \perror_replicate:nn #1 #2
  {
    \__perror_replicate_loop:w #2
      \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop {#1} { }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_loop:w #1 \q_recursion_stop
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
      { \__perror_replicate_parse_token:N }
      {
        \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
          { \__perror_replicate_nested:n }
          { \__perror_replicate_output_space:w }
      }
    #1 \q_recursion_stop
  }
\use:nn { \cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_output_space:w } { ~ }
  { \__perror_replicate_output:nw { ~ } }
\cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_output:nw #1 #2 \q_recursion_stop #3 #4
  { \__perror_replicate_loop:w #2 \q_recursion_stop {#3} { #4 #1 } }
\cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_nested:n #1 #2 \q_recursion_stop #3
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \__perror_replicate_output:nw
      { { \perror_replicate:nn {#3} {#1} } }
    #2 \q_recursion_stop {#3}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_end:nn #1 #2 { \exp_not:n {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_parse_token:N #1
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn #1
      { \__perror_replicate_end:nn }
    \__perror_replicate_if_digit:NTF #1
      { \__perror_replicate_collect_number:nw }
      { \__perror_replicate_output:nw }
    {#1}
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \__perror_replicate_if_digit:N #1 { TF }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w 10 < 9 \token_to_str:N #1 \exp_stop_f:
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_collect_number:nw #1 #2 \q_recursion_stop
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#2}
      { \__perror_replicate_collect_number:nN }
      { \__perror_replicate_finish_number:nw }
    {#1} #2 \q_recursion_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_collect_number:nN #1 #2
  {
    \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop_do:Nn #2
      {
        \__perror_replicate_finish_number:nw {#1}
        \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop
      }
    \__perror_replicate_if_digit:NTF #2
      { \__perror_replicate_collect_number:nw { #1 #2 } }
      { \__perror_replicate_finish_number:nw {#1} #2 }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__perror_replicate_finish_number:nw #1 #2 \q_recursion_stop #3
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \__perror_replicate_output:nw
      { \prg_replicate:nn {#1} {#3} }
    #2 \q_recursion_stop {#3}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Replicate{3(2)2(1)}

\Replicate[Z]{3(2)2(1)}

\Replicate[(Z)]{3(2)2(1)}

\Replicate[Z]{3 \textbf{(2) 2}( 1 )}

\edef\zzzzzzzzzzzz{\Replicate[Z]{3\textbf{(2)2}(1)}}

\texttt{\meaning\zzzzzzzzzzzz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A piece of cake using LuaLaTeX (but yes, only works with LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\newcommand\myexpand[2]{%
\directlua{local function myexpand(x,s) return (x:gsub("(\csstring\%d+)", function(u) return s:rep(math.floor(u)) end)) end tex.sprint(myexpand(\luastring{#1},\luastring{#2}))}}
\begin{document}
\myexpand{(3)2(2)1}{A}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, this is extremely nice to have access to a full programming language. But, I am stuck with the good old TeX macros! But, nice answer. Thanks!

Comment: @perror No problem. When you have the opportunity (or the will) to change, there's a solution for you `:)`

Comment: I am looking at LuaTeX and Xetex more and more seriously these days! :-)

Answer (score 4):

A recursive implementation using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myexpand@}[2]{%
  \xdef\@sequence{#2}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{1}{#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{2}{#1#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{3}{#1#1#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{4}{#1#1#1#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{5}{#1#1#1#1#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{6}{#1#1#1#1#1#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{7}{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{8}{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
  \patchcmd{\@sequence}{9}{#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1#1}{\myexpand@{#1}{\@sequence}}{}%
}
\newcommand{\myexpand}[2]{%
  \myexpand@{#1}{#2}% Replace numbers with copies of #1
  \@sequence% Print sequence
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myexpand{A}{(3)2(2)1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are interested in some sort of syntax-error-management—which I would probably *not* be as the code of David Carlisle is considerably shorter and faster as long as the user obeys the rules;-)—I can offer a rather slow `\romannumeral`-expansion-based routine

```
\expandtoA{⟨sequence of numbers denoted by digits and separated from each other by properly matched not nested parentheses⟩}{⟨tokens in case of error⟩}
```

which does without whatsoever TeX-extensions and delivers the result after two expansion-steps/after two "hits" by `\expandafter`.

Digits and parentheses  in the 1st argument must be explicit character tokens of category code 12(other).

Empty pairs of matched unnested parentheses are allowed.

Spaces are not allowed.

In case the 1st argument is not of the described pattern, *⟨tokens in case of error⟩* will be delivered instead of a "conversion" to "A".
You can use *⟨tokens in case of error⟩* for triggering a LaTeX-error-message or whatever.

There definitely is room for improvement/shortcuts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter    
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@Exchange, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, 
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull, 
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens, \UD@replicate
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does neither contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category code 1 or 2 nor contain tokens of category code 6:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category code
%%                                1 or 2 and without tokens of
%%                                category code 6>}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[3]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral
      \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#3{\relax}#1#2}{}}{}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and spit that out
%% nested in braces.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#2{{##1}}}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \UD@replicate{<number>}{<tokens>}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@replicateloop[3]{%
  \if m#3\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
  {\UD@replicateloop{#1}{#2#1}}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@replicate[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}%
                                      {\UD@replicateloop{#2}{}}\relax
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckLeftParen}{(}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckRightParen}{)}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckZero}{0}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckOne}{1}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckTwo}{2}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckThree}{3}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckFour}{4}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckFive}{5}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckSix}{6}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckSeven}{7}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckEight}{8}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\UD@CheckNine}{9}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\expandtoA[2]{%
  \romannumeral\expandtoALoop{#1}{#2}{}{}{}%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\expandtoALoop[5]{%
  % #1 Remaining argument to examine
  % #2 Tokens in case of error
  % #3 Flag denoting how next number must terminate: 
  %    Empty -> next number must terminate due to opening parenthesis or emptiness of remaining argument to examine.
  %    Not empty -> next number must terminate due to closing parenthesis.
  % #4 Digits of next number gathered so far.
  % #5 Result gathered so far.
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@replicate{#4}{A}}%
       {\UD@stopromannumeral#5}%
    }{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{(}{\UD@CheckLeftParen}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
           \romannumeral
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@replicate{#4}{A}}{\UD@stopromannumeral#5}%
        }%
        {\expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{\relax}{}}%
      }{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{)}{\UD@CheckRightParen}{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{%
          \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
             \romannumeral
             \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
             \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@replicate{#4}{A}}{\UD@stopromannumeral#5(})%
          }%
          {\expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{}{}}%
        }%
      }{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{0}{\UD@CheckZero}{%
          \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#40}{#5}%
        }{%
          \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{1}{\UD@CheckOne}{%
            \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#41}{#5}%
          }{%
            \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{2}{\UD@CheckTwo}{%
              \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#42}{#5}%
            }{%
              \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{3}{\UD@CheckThree}{%
                \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#43}{#5}%
              }{%
                \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{4}{\UD@CheckFour}{%
                  \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#44}{#5}%
                }{%
                  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{5}{\UD@CheckFive}{%
                    \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#45}{#5}%
                  }{%
                    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{6}{\UD@CheckSix}{%
                      \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#46}{#5}%
                    }{%
                      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{7}{\UD@CheckSeven}{%
                        \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#47}{#5}%
                      }{%
                        \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{8}{\UD@CheckEight}{%
                          \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#48}{#5}%
                        }{%
                          \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#1}{9}{\UD@CheckNine}{%
                            \expandafter\expandtoALoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}{#49}{#5}%
                          }{%
                            \UD@stopromannumeral#2%
                          }%
                        }%
                      }%
                    }%
                  }%
                }%
              }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\message{\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandtoA{1(2)3(4)5(6)7(8)9(10)()(11)}{ErrorText}}}%

\message{\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandtoA{1(2)3(4)5(6)7(89(10)()(11)}{ErrorText}}}%

\end{document}
```

The above code delivers the messages

```
A(AA)AAA(AAAA)AAAAA(AAAAAA)AAAAAAA(AAAAAAAA)AAAAAAAAA(AAAAAAAAAA)()(AAAAAAAAAAA)
```

and

```
ErrorText
```

to the terminal. (ErrorText with the second call as here parentheses are not properly matched.)

Comment: users who input syntax errors deserve no sympathy!! :-)

Comment: Interesting code, I really appreciate it (and, user are making mistakes, this is why they are still users and not developers! :-) ).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fully agree. But which users do?  ;->